# Logback configuration issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, logback

I'm using Spring Boot 2.3.2. I'm trying to configure logback to continue outputing to the console EXACTLY how it does today (ansi and all), plus mirror it to a log file in the exact same format (ansi and all). I want ALL the log files to be in the format of ${spring.application.name}.YYYY-MM-DD.log including the active one and I want to keep 7 days worth of files, so I've got it configured like this:

application.properties:

```
logging.file.name=${spring.application.name}
logging.file.path=/var/logs
logging.pattern.file=%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID}){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n%wEx
```

logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/console-appender.xml" />
    <timestamp key="byDate" datePattern="yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${LOG_PATH}/${LOG_FILE}.${byDate}.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

This results in a collision error between file and fileNamePattern. I get what the error means and I can fix it by removing the date stamp from file, but there is no way to have all the files in a consistent format?

If I remove the timestamp from the active file, then it works except for the next issue...

The other issue that I have is that the logfile never gets written too until I shutdown the application.

Answer (score 0):

> This results in a collision error between file and fileNamePattern. I
> get what the error means and I can fix it by removing the date stamp
> from file, but there is no way to have all the files in a consistent
> format?

Here :

```
<fileNamePattern>${LOG_PATH}/${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

you don't have to specify  `${LOG_PATH}`.   It is a filename pattern not a full path.
That should be that :

```
<fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
```

> The other issue that I have is that the logfile never gets written too
> until I shutdown the application.

Not sure but it looks a file locking.  Try to ensure that no process locks the file.

As an additional remark : you specified :

```
logging.file.name=${spring.application.name}
logging.file.path=/var/logs
```

But the [spring boot logging doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging) specify to reference the one or the other :

> you need to set a logging.file.name or logging.file.path property (for
> example, in your application.properties).

Valuing `logging.file.name` such as the following respects better the documentation :

```
logging.file.name=/var/log/${spring.application.name}
```

Comment: Yes that is normal. You specified `ss` in the pattern. It means that you want to a rolling on second. Remove `ss` and you would have that by hour (because `HH` is still there in the pattern).  And so for :)

Comment: I deleted my previous comments cuz this behavior is just bizarre. 1) I had to move the logging props to bootstrap.properties or I was getting undefined variable errors 2) I *DO* need LOG_PATH on the pattern or it writes to the workspace directory

Comment: regarding the logging.file.name and logging.file.path, please see docs for Boot 2.3.2, you referenced a doc for 2.1.1. In 2.3.2, those props are documented and logging.file is deprecated.

Comment: still doesn't seem to flush to the active file... nobody is touching that file except the logging system.

Comment: You are right. I didn't know for that recent update. Whatever you specified the two properties while only a single should be valued.